# Loading SKTileSet from .sks in Playgrounds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I currently have a SKTileSet set up within a .sks file. I can load the SKTileSet completely fine if I'm utilizing the iOS Simulator. However, when I try to load the .sks in a Xcode Playground, I get the following error:

> SKTexture: Error loading image resource:

Is there any way I can load a SKTileSet in Playgrounds without having to manually create the SKTileDefinition, SKTileGroupRule, and SKTileGroup manually?

Thank you!